# How to use the Geo-location's Latitude and longitude values to move to the location

Tags: google-maps, search, geolocation

I am currently using the Geolocation in a search bar in my App. after Searching for the location, i get the geolocation information.

However i want to use latitude and longitude values returned to make the map navigate to that location on the map.

The code i am used for geolocate is the below

`private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: geolocating");`

```
    String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(SearchActivity.this);
    List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "geoLocate: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }

    if(list.size() > 0){
        Address address = list.get(0);
        ;

        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: found a location: " + address.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}`
```

For example Searching for Manchester i get the results, but i just want to use its longitude and latitude values to navigate to it on the map

`D/SearchActivity: geoLocate: geolocating
D/SearchActivity: geoLocate: found a location: Address[addressLines=[0:"Manchester, UK"],feature=Manchester,admin=England,sub-admin=Greater Manchester,locality=Manchester,thoroughfare=null,postalCode=null,countryCode=GB,countryName=United Kingdom,hasLatitude=true,latitude=53.480759299999995,hasLongitude=true,longitude=-2.2426304999999997,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]`

Answer (score 0):

added into geolocate and it worked :)

`moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()),
                                DEFAULT_ZOOM);`